# Trying to run random number in instance's index but i get index out of range error

Tags: mysql, swift, struct, instance

I created a struct to connect to mysql database and then created an instance for it. When I try to run a random number (within the size of the array), I get a default number of 0, yet my database id starts from 1, therefor i get an error of index out of range.

```
import UIKit
struct PickUpLine: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let setup: String
}

class PickUpLines: UIViewController {

    private var pul = [PickUpLine ] ()

    @IBOutlet var PULViewController: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var PULabel: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        downloadJson()

    }



    @IBAction func generateRandPUL(_ sender: Any) {

        showRandPUL ()

    }

    func showRandPUL (){

        let randomPUL = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(pul.count)))
        PULabel.text = pul[randomPUL].setup // index out of range

    }

    func downloadJson () {
    let url = "https://icebreakerappinc.herokuapp.com/pickuplines"

    print(url)

    //creating let for the url to bond with the link above #2
    guard let url2  = URL (string: url) else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url2) { (data,response,err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {
            let PULurl = try JSONDecoder().decode([PickUpLine].self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.PULViewController.reloadInputViews()
                self.pul = PULurl
            }
        }catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:" , jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use **`randomElement`** on `pul` `array` like,

```
let randomPUL = pul.randomElement()
puLabel.text = randomPUL?.setup
```

> Call randomElement() to select a random element from an array or
>   another collection.
>
> **Returns**
>
> A random element from the collection. If the collection is empty, the
>   method returns nil.

**Note:** Use `camel case` for naming your variables. It should be `puLabel` instead of `PULabel`.

**Update:**

Here is how the `PickUpLines` controller should look like,

```
class PickUpLines: UIViewController {
    private var pul = [PickUpLine ] ()

    func showRandPUL (){
        let randomPUL = pul.randomElement()
        puLabel.text = randomPUL?.setup
    }
    //rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: Value of type '[PickUpLine]' has no member 'randomElement'

Comment: Call `randomElement()` on pul not `randomPUL`. In your code, `pul` is an `array` of type `PickUpLine`.

Comment: Swift version 5.0.1

Comment: It should work then. Add the exact code you're using.

Comment: i did called it on pul ( PickupLine's instance)

Comment: pul in the code you gave is not  PickupLines's instance. Its  array of PickupLines. Kindly update the question if you've done any changes.

Comment: the entire code is on the original question post above.

Comment: `private var pul = [PickUpLine ] ()`. See that's an array.

Comment: indeed it is ,yet randomElement () is unsuitable to it :-\

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try that in a separate project and see if that works.

Comment: tried it buddy, still  not working ;-/

it seems like my array is defaulted to 0 [ i tried to print it and it always started off with value of zero]

Comment: Is the error still there.? Can you print the content of `pul` array.

Comment: first i printed the randomPUL and it always show me the value zero,then i tried to print the pul[1].setup and got error of index out of range.

i guess it doesnt get the database from my mysql,bc the json works fine.

Comment: 0 is not an array. Its an Int. Show the code where you're assigning pul's value.

Comment: The code seems right. just check if you'r calling generateRandPUL before the data is fetched.

Comment: ok so one thing is for sure:
the first time i get into my PickupLine(viewController) the default value of the array is zero[like it doesnt exist maybe],if i go back and for again [to the same viewcontroller] then the default is not zero and the app works fine...any ideas what can be the problem?

Comment: ok i updated my xcode and your code works fine! thank you so much! very useful!

Comment: I did! since i don't have 15 point reputation it didnt allowed me.

by the way the problem was a matter of time, literally , since i was retrieving the data via JSON into the app, this action takes few seconds and just then i can generate a random number to take place in the array into the pulLabel.text.

a friend advised me to use print ("started") at the beginning of the json function code and a print ("finished") at the end of the same function code, just then i realized it was just a matter of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be its work

```
 guard let count = pul.count - 1 , count >= 0 else { return }
 let randomPUL = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
```